# Vue.js 2 - Selected item from a re-populated list is not refreshing changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Given the following set of data in my vue.js 2 component:

```
data() {
  return {
    listItems: [{
       id: '',
       name: '',
       subItems: []
    }],
    selectedItem: '',
    hasSelectedItem: false
  }
}
```

I'm filling up the `listItems` with a REST API and selecting a specific item in the view:

```
getItems() {
            axios.get(this.base_url + '/items/all', {headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token}}).then(response => {

                this.listItems = response.data

            }).catch(e => {
                this.errors.push(e)
            });
},
```

Then at some point in the UI I select a specific `item` from `listItems` by something like this:

```
<el-dropdown size="medium" @command="handleCommand">
<el-button size="small" type="primary">
    Select item<i class="el-icon-arrow-down el-icon--right"></i>
</el-button>
<el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
    <div v-for="(item) in listItems">
        <el-dropdown-item :disabled="selectedItem === item"
          :command="item">
          {{ item.name }}
      </el-dropdown-item>
  </div>
  <el-dropdown-item divided>
    New Item
  </el-dropdown-item>
</el-dropdown-menu>
</el-dropdown>
```

and the function:

```
handleCommand(selected) {
  this.selectedItem = selected;
  this.hasSelectedItem = true
}
```

The problem is that whenever I add new stuff into its `subItems[]` by a POST request to the server and call again the `getItems()` to refresh the `listItems` list, the `selectedItem` stays as before and doesn't refresh.

Shouldn't this be an assignment by reference?

What's the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**
Maybe I should re-ask this in a different way:
If I have a list of `items`,
and in addition, I have a `selectedItem` reference to one of them,
what's the right way to **update** `selectedItem` on a member change from within the list?

Comment: Can you attach your `template` and also the method from where `listItems` is updating through api?

Comment: As `setItem[]` is an array you should use [Vue.$set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) for it to be _reactive_.

Comment: @Vucko, not always. Depends on the usage. If the all code he uses is  posted, then it is OK. Though your suggestion is always a good suggestion (precisely because people frequently don't post all of the relevant code).

Comment: @magnoz You are saying `this.selectedItem` does not update. Does `this.hasSelectedItem` updates (goes from `false` to `true`)?

Comment: @Vucko sounds like a good suggestion. However, in this case, I'm not "adding" to the array, but posting to a REST service who adds the item in the database and I ask the server the whole list again, so I'm actually replacing the array by a new one with the same reference.

Comment: @adcjunior yes, I update it manually whenever I select an item. I might use a computed instead

Comment: I'm asking if you can confirm `hasSelectedItem` changes and `selectedItem` doesn't. Because if both don't update, then it could be a problem with the `this` the moment `handleCommand` is called. If `hasSelectedItem` updates but `selectedItem` doesn't, then it is very weird indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid comparing object use 
`:disabled="selectedItem.id === item.id"`
instead of 
`:disabled="selectedItem === item"`

also in your `data()` method use `selectedItem: {}`

```
data() {
  return {
    listItems: [{
       id: '',
       name: '',
       subItems: []
    }],
    selectedItem: {},
    hasSelectedItem: false
  }
}
```

**Update**

You are partially right about having `selectedItem` by reference, but when  you get the list of items again from server you replace the list of items and loose the object reference as well. You can refresh the `selectedItem` after getting data from server like this :

```
getItems() {
axios.get(this.base_url + '/items/all', {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token
    }
}).then(response => {

    this.listItems = response.data
    if (this.selectedItem.id) {
        this.selectedItem = this.listItems.find((item) => {
            return item.id === this.selectedItem.id;
        })
    }


}).catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
});
```

},

Comment: that doesn't fix the issue, however thanks for the advice, good catch

Comment: @magnoz please check it again, I updated my answer and put more details

Answer (score 0):

Try binding `:key` with `v-for`.

```
 <div v-for="(item) in listItems" :key="item">
```

---

```
<el-dropdown size="medium" @command="handleCommand">
<el-button size="small" type="primary">
    Select item<i class="el-icon-arrow-down el-icon--right"></i>
</el-button>
<el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown">
    <div v-for="(item) in listItems" :key="item">
        <el-dropdown-item :disabled="selectedItem === item"
          :command="item">
          {{ item.name }}
      </el-dropdown-item>
  </div>
  <el-dropdown-item divided>
    New Item
  </el-dropdown-item>
</el-dropdown-menu>
</el-dropdown>
```

Comment: the key should be a primitive, so I tried with item.id. Anyways the problem persists.
The change is that i'm actually adding stuff to the `subItems[]`of the item, which is ok at `listItems` but it's not being refreshed in `selectedItem`